# C++ string name of class for casting

Tags: c++

I know I can use the Registry pattern for creating objects from a string but is there a way to  cast by string and then call methods of the casted object by string as well?

Comment: are you saying you want something like `std::map<std::string, std::function<>>`?

Comment: You just use the registry pattern on your class methods too.

Comment: You're basically reinventing the fun parts of reflection and message passing here.  By the time the infrastructure is in place, what you have won't really be a C++ object anymore -- it'll be somewhere between Java and Objective-C.

Comment: cHao I agree, but it'll still be C++ and crossplatform (including all mobile) and faster than Java.

paddy It would seem a little different as I'd need to store function pointers and objects I would think. I'll play around with it.

A big issue is still how to cast this way. I'm defining interactions in an xml file which is why I'd need this.